# Ubuntu 18.10 (Wayland) screen sharing for Windows OS

Tags: remote-desktop, vnc

I'm looking for a way to share my Ubuntu 18.10 desktop experience via network to a Windows computer.
I need to share my real desktop. This was possible on older Ubuntu via built-in service called "Screen sharing" and VNC client on Windows OS.
It was working perfect until Ubuntu 18.10 had switched to Wayland not x.org.
Now when I try to use same built in "screen sharing service" when I try to gain access I see a black screen but I can move my mouse over VNC Windows client.

I need it exactly that way, because I have open applications on my desktop and I need access to them, I know I could try installing just VNC server, but that creates a separate session and requires running another instance of software... here I was able to leave my programming software open and get back from VNC...

Why does the built-in option not work?
I can't see on "login screen" option to choose x.org instead of wayland.

Any thoughts?

Comment: Wayland doesn't let any application to "see" the desktop screen. That's why you can't even record the screen. Ubuntu on Xorg is genrally listed simply as "Ubuntu" on login screen. For example [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XzhEX.png)

Comment: I understand that,  could You kindly take look how it looks on my machine ->
https://i.imgur.com/TA8fsDe.jpg

Comment: ... and Wayland is not the default in 18.10 (clean install), x.org is.

Comment: It looks you installed XFCE and somehow messed Xorg that came with 18.10 out-of-the-box. Try installing it again. Use `sudo apt install xorg`.

Comment: Thank You, i was sure it's problem with Wayland.
Solution to my problem was deleting file in my home dir called .xsession and inside i had lines for starting up xfce with was removed. That file try run non existing xfce and crash with empty screen. Now i can confirm it's working out of box.  Thank You again for help and showing me right direction.

Comment: So nothing to do with Wayland after all :)

Comment: @GabrielaGarcia - Yes it was just inexperienced me trying blame Wayland:)

Answer (score 2):

Solution to my problem was deleting file in my home directory called .xsession and  inside was lines used for starting up xfce over standard VNC with was later removed. That file upon connecting try run non existing xfce and end with empty screen while VNC client try connect to shared screen. Now after removal I can confirm it's working out of box allowing me to remotely control my real desktop.